# Android how to draw 400 similar pictures (only different colors) efficiently at runtime

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I know that similar questions have been asked but I couldn't find a good awnser and I am an android beginner. I want to be able to draw houses (screenshot) during runtime. So far I have bean able to create 400 imageviews with an invisible image in them and at run-time swap the image. 
I feel like this is extremely inefficient and I seem to have some memory problems. The images do not need to be clickable. I couldn't find a way to add imageviews during runtime. Could I maybe utilize a gridview (seems difficult due to the structure of the board). 
Thank you

[image: Android app with some houses drawn]

Comment: Yes, `View` objects tend to be large, you shouldn't use them like this. You'll probably want to have a single subclassed `View` and use its `Canvas` to draw `BitmapDrawable`s. Using OpenGL is too far away from your current solution and `Canvas` draw operations are hardware accelerated since Android 3 or so. And still not slow on Android 2.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere you to use AndEngine. You can fine a good toturial here (http://www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html) or you can create your custom view and override onDraw(Canvas canvas) method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, right,paint);

  super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```